# In Email Message record, why IsBounced not visible in salesforce?

Tags: apex, email, salesforce-id

I have a requirement where I want to show IsBounced field on Email message layout which display target email id is valid or not.
FLS is visible to all profiles but field is not visible to anyone.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> To see IsBounced field, enable bounce management in your Org.
>   With bounce handling, reps know which lead, contact, or person account has a bad email address, and they know which specific email wasn’t delivered.

To display email bounce information in the activity timeline, Enhanced Email must be enabled.

NOTE:- The activity timeline doesn’t show the bounce warning for list emails.

1. From Setup, click Email, then click Deliverability.
2. Select Activate bounce

The fields Email Bounced Date and Email Bounced Reason appear in the contact, lead, and person account list views.

Use the Email Bounced Reason field in list views to find bounced contacts; leads, and person account. Also use it in reports to filter contacts, leads, and person accounts; and in workflows to create workflow rules based on bounce status.

If the field isn’t empty, the contact, lead, or person account has bounced.

**USER PERMISSIONS NEEDED**

> To enable email tracking: Customize Application and Modify All Data

Reference:-

- [EmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm)
- [Enable Email Bounce Handling](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_bounce_enable.htm&type=5)

Comment: thank you, Sanket for a response. bounce management is already enabled in my org but I am not able to see IsBounced field.

Comment: In Lightning, after sending an email with an invalid address from Case to a contact, how can we check whether it is bounced?